# Docker login into kube cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've create a private repo on docker hub and trying to pull that image into my kubernetes cluster. I can see the documentations suggest to do this

`kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`

I am already logged in, and i change path to ~/.docker/config.json but it keeps giving me

`error: error reading ~./docker/config.json: no such file or directory`

despite the fact if i type `cat ~/.docker/config.json` it displays the content, meaning there is a file.

So in other words how to properly authenticate and be able to push private images into kube cluster?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> error: error reading ~./docker/config.json: no such file or directory
>                      ^^^^ ?
> ```

`~./docker/config.json` does not seem valid:
`~/.docker/config.json` would

To remove any doubt, try the full path instead of `~`:

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/auser/.docker/config.json \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Comment: In my case, I really had to pass the absolute path instead of `~`because the latter could not be resolved.

Comment: @SparkFountain OK. What version of Kubernetes, Docker and OS are you using?

Comment: Kubernetes: Client Version v1.17.4, Server Version v1.17.3; Docker: 19.03.8, OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G3020)

Comment: Full path worked for me. I am using WSL 2. Not sure if that could be related?

Comment: @NathanClement Possible: WSL2 was not yet available when I initially wrote this answer.